# How can I connect to the "In-Sight OPC Server" through node.js without knowing the Port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, opc-ua

This is what im trying to create, This is all new to me. I hope someone can help me.

```
//this is the part I cannot figure out, maby anyone knows a tool how to find this port
const endpointUrl = "opc.tcp://145.49.49.3:???";

const opcua = require("node-opcua");
const AttributeIds = opcua.AttributeIds;
const OPCUAClient = opcua.OPCUAClient;

(async function main(){

    const client = new OPCUAClient({});
    await client.connect(endpointUrl);
    const session = await client.createSession({userName: "admin", password: ""});

    const dataValue = await session.read({nodeId: "ns=1;s=AcquisitionCount",attributeId: AttributeIds.Value});
    console.log(`Count is ${dataValue.value.value.toPrecision(3)}°C.`);

    await client.closeSession(session,true);
    await client.disconnect();

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default port is 4840, but you’re going to have to figure it out one way or another.

Normally the server you are connecting to has the full endpoint URL, port included, documented or listed in some configuration somewhere.